# Laravel: Script message is not showing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to delete a row from my database after clicking a `href` link. It is working fine. But after completing deletion I want show a message to the user. but it is not showing. my if condition is also not working...it is showing :

> Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted
>   to int

My code is here:

```
<?php
public function postDelete($booked_by) {
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $booking_id = DB::table('bookings')
            ->select('id')
            ->where('booked_by', '=', $user_id)
            ->get();

    // dd($booking_id);

    if ($user_id == $booking_id) {
        $user = DB::table('bookings')
                ->where('booked_by', '=', $user_id)
                ->delete();

        return back();
        $message = "Your booking is canceled";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');       </script>";
        else {
            $message = "You can't delete which is booked by others";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        }


        return back();
    }
}
?>
```

what should I change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `Flash Message` in this case:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#flash-data

If you use alert message it's really dangerous with XSS bugs.

Comment: actually my condition is not working i guess...it is showing that `Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int` i guess this condition is not working ` if($user_id == $booking_id)` what should i do here?

Comment: @incorporeal you need to change `if($user_id == $booking_id)` to `if($user_id == $booking_id->id)`

Comment: not working..showing this `Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$id`

Comment: @incorporeal change `DB::table('bookings')
                        ->select('id')
                        ->where('booked_by', '=', $user_id)
                        ->get();` From `->get()` To `->first()`

Answer (score 0):

Move to `return back();` after echoing message inside if condition will probably work. But it is not right way to do.

Right way is to pass message with redirection like this

```
  return back()->with("message","your message");
```

And display message in view

```
  {{ $message or "" }}
```

Comment: actually my condition is not working i guess...it is showing that `Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int` i guess this condition is not working ` if($user_id == $booking_id)` what should i do here? @niklesh